# Generic Class and passing derived data type

Tags: java, generics

I do have a problem in the last line of execution though I pass derived data type. Not able to figure out. Thanks.

```
     public class ExtendedDHvalue extends DHvalue {}



    public class DerivedHolderUnique<T> {

    private Class<? extends T> a;

    public DerivedHolderUnique(Class<? extends T> a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Class<? extends T> getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(Class<? extends T> a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ExtendedDHvalue eDV = new ExtendedDHvalue();
        DerivedHolderUnique<DHvalue> dhu = new DerivedHolderUnique<DHvalue>(eDV);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor takes parameter of type `Class<? extends T>` and you're passing an argument that extends `T` to it. You should change those two lines to:

```
Class<ExtendedDHvalue> eDV = ExtendedDHvalue.class;
DerivedHolderUnique<DHvalue> dhu = new DerivedHolderUnique<DHvalue>(eDV);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DerivedHolderUnique` constructor requires a `Class` instance, not
an `ExtendedDHvalue` instance. This is what causes the compile-time error.

You should think if you actually want

`private Class<? extends T> a;`

or

`private T a;`

and then rework your `DerivedHolderUnique` class accordingly.
I tend to think you want the latter but you should know better.